# Accessing shared instance Swift, Objective-C equivilant

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert my app's app delegate from Objective-C to Swift and am struggling to convert this one line of code (I am creating a hybrid project and am starting with converting the app delegate):

```
    [GBConfig sharedInstance].agency = [GBAgency georgiaTechAgency];
```

I have tried

```
    GBConfig.sharedInstance.agency = GBAgency.georgiaTechAgency
```

and

```
    GBConfig.sharedInstnace(agency) = GBAgency(georgiaTechAgency)
```

and many other lines of code but I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to Swift.

Comment: `GBConfig.sharedInstance().agency = GBAgency.georgiaTechAgency()`... but I think there's a more Swift-y way to handle factory methods. (The right hand side)

Comment: I think it should be like `GBConfig.sharedInstance()` - have you tried that?

Comment: So, no error messages are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to tell you where the problem is, if we do not know anything about the code. But (making lots of assumptions) you can try

```
var config : GBConfig = GBConfig.sharedInstance()
config.setAgency(GBAgency.georgiaTechAgency())
```

or more direct

```
GBConfig.sharedInstance().agency = GBAgency.georgiaTechAgency()
```

But this is a Swift syntax related question, so maybe a good book for Swift would be a good starting point.